# SQL Server "SELECT COUNT(field) FROM tblname" returns null

Tags: c#, sql-server

This is pretty strange.  I have a very simple SQL query in my c# application, which counts records in a SQL Server table.  The code snippet is as follows:

```
    // Returns the number of ports defined for a given slot.
    int returnval = 0;
    connection.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(Slotted_Port_UID) FROM tblSlottedCardPorts WHERE Slot_ID = @SlotID ", connection);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SlotID", EquipmentSlotID);
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        if (!reader.IsDBNull(0))
        {
            returnval = reader.GetInt32(0);
        }
    }
    reader.Close();
    connection.Close();
    return returnval;
```

When I copy and paste the SQL statement directly in to SQL server mgmt studio, the query returns as expected, returning 0 or a positive integer, depending on the number of rows.  However, though the code passes the .HawRows condition, it fails on the reader.IsDBNull(0) condition.  The tblSlottedCardPorts exists, and the Slotted_Port_UID column is a unique integer.  Any suggestions on this?  I can't see why COUNT would ever return a Null value, since no joins or other factors are involved.

Thanks for any advice with this!

Mitchell

Answer (score 7):

For a query of this type - use `.ExecuteScalar()` instead of a datareader

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx

Answer (score 5):

You need to call `Read` to get to the first row.

```
if (reader.HasRows)
{
    reader.Read();
    if (!reader.IsDBNull(0))
    {
        returnval = reader.GetInt32(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I also would remove the IsDbNull() check as it never will be null due the query

Comment: Ugh!  I can't believe I missed that.  Thanks for catching this!

Answer (score 2):

A more simpler statement is

```
 int returnval = 0;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(Slotted_Port_UID) FROM tblSlottedCardPorts WHERE Slot_ID = @SlotID ", connection);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SlotID", EquipmentSlotID);
                returnval = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());

        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I had something like this in SQL:

```
declare @NumberOfRecords int;
select @NumberOfRecords=count(*) from ...
return @NumberOfRecords;
```

Stored procedure run ok from SQL Management Studio, but returned null when calling from code. After removing `@NumberOfRecords` variable, the query worked from code:

```
select count(*) from ...
```